# Проблема с версткой. Образовался горизонтальный бегунок

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Привет всем, верстал статический макет в 1200пх, с контейнером в теге боди(за контейнером серый цвет и контент выделен тенью) и вообщем на каком-то шаге появился горизонтальный бегунок, от чего в силу своей неопытности я не знаю. Подскажите из-за чего образовался бегунок?

```css
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed,
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup,
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure,
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
a {
    text-decoration: none;  
    color: #000;
}
.container {
    width: 1200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 15px 0px rgba(0, 1, 1, 0.2);
    background-color: #fff;
}
html {
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
}
/*
======================
ТИПОГРАФИКА
======================
*/
body {
    font-family: 'PT Sans', 'Arial', sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
h2 {
    color:  #000000;
    font-size: 21px;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 21px;
}
p {
    color:  #333333;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 21px;
}
/*
======================
CLEARFIX
======================
*/
.clearfix::after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}
/*
======================
HEADER
======================
*/
.main-header {
    height: 56px;
    background: #fff;
}
.main-header ul {
    font-size: 0px;
}
.main-header li {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 26px;
    font-weight: 700;
}
.main-header a {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    padding: 15px 0px;
}
.left-navigation {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 72px;
}
.left-navigation li:first-child {
    margin-right: 145px;
}
.right-navigation {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 72px;
}
.right-navigation li:last-child {
    margin-left: 160px;
}
.logo-bg {
    position: relative;
    left: 540px;
    top: -58px;
    z-index: 1;
}
.logo {
   position: relative;
    left: 168px;
    z-index: 2;
}
/*
======================
FIRST
======================
*/
.first {
    height: 508px;
    background: url(../img/background%20photo.jpg) no-repeat center top;
} 
.first img {
    display: block;
}
.first_img {
    padding-top: 75px;
    padding-left: 506px;
}
.second_img {
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-left: 513px;
}
.third_img {
    padding-top: 45px;
    padding-left: 371px;
}
.four_img {
    padding-top: 62px;
    padding-left: 452px;
}
.white-bg {
    padding-top: 27px;
}
/*
======================
TITLE
======================
*/
.title {
    height: 217px;
}
.title h1 {
    color:  #000000;
    font-size: 21px;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 26px;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 61px;
}
.title p {
    padding-top: 33px;
    text-align: center;
}
/*
======================
TWO-BLOCKS
======================
*/
.two-blocks {
    height: 256px;
}
.two-blocks-left {
    width: 400px;
    height: 256px;
    background: #82b4d3;
    float: left;
}
.white-text {
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
}
.two-blocks-left h2 {
    padding-top: 55px;
}
.two-blocks-left p {
    padding-top: 25px;
}
.two-blocks-right {
    float: right;
    width: 800px;
    height: 256px;
    background: url(../img/bg-two-blocks.jpg) no-repeat;
}
/*
======================
FEATURES
======================
*/
.features-item {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    float: left; 
    height: 330px;
    width: 400px;
    padding-top: 60px;
    text-align: center;
}
.features-item h2 {
    padding-top: 30px;
}
.features-item p {
    padding-top: 25px;
}
/*
======================
TWO-BLOCKS-2
======================
*/
.two-blocks-2 {

}
.two-blocks-2-left {
    float: left;
    width: 800px;
    height: 256px;
    background: url(../img/bg-two-block-2.jpg) no-repeat;
}
.two-blocks-2-right {
    width: 400px;
    height: 256px;
    background: #82b4d3;
    float: right;
}
.two-blocks-2-right h2 {
    padding-top: 55px;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
}
.two-blocks-2-right p {
    padding-top: 25px;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
}
/*
======================
FEATURES-2
======================
*/
.features-2 {
    background: #efefef;
}
.features-item-2 {
    float: left; 
    height: 256px;
    width: 400px;
    text-align: center;
}
.features-item-2 h2 {
    padding-top: 48px;
}
.features-item-2 p {
    padding-top: 25px;
}
/*
======================
LINE
======================
*/
.line {
    height: 291px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 57px;
}
.line h3 {
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #000;
    line-height: 24px;
}
.line p {
    padding-top: 30px;
}
.maps {
    background: url(../img/map.jpg) no-repeat;
    width: 1200px;
    height: 593px;
}
/*
===========
FOOTER
===========
*/
footer {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background: #fff;
    opacity: 0.9;
    height: 120px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 2700px;
}
.footer-div {
    float: left;
    width: 400px;
    height: 120px;
    text-align: center;
}

.footer-div-1 {
    font-size: 21px;
    line-height: 26px;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #000;
    padding-top: 50px;
}
.footer-div-2 {
    padding-top: 35px;
}
.footer-div-3 p,
.footer-div-3 img {
    display: inline-block;
}
.footer-div-3 img {
    padding-top: 41px;
}
.footer-div-3 p {
    position: relative;
    top: -14px;
    left: -4px;
}
.soc {
    width: 46px;
    height: 48px;
    background: #81b3d2;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 5px;
    line-height: 48px;
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>sedona</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans:400,700&amp;subset=cyrillic" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body class="container">
  
    <header class="main-header clearfix">
       <div class="left-navigation">
           <ul>
               <li>
                   <a href="#">информация</a>
               </li>
               <li>
                   <a href="#">фото и видео</a>
               </li>
           </ul>
       </div>
        <div class="right-navigation">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">карта штата</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">гостиница</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
           
       <div class="logo">
           <img src="img/Logo.png" alt="logo">
       </div>
       <div class="logo-bg">
           <img src="img/logo-bg.png" alt="">
       </div>
   </header>
    <section class="first">
           <img class = "first_img"src="img/Welcome.png" alt="">
        <img class = "second_img" src="img/to%20the%20gorgeous.png" alt="">
        <img class = "third_img" src="img/Sedona.png" alt="">
        <img class = "four_img" src="img/Because%20the%20Grand%20%20Canyon%20sucks_.png" alt="">
          <img class="white-bg" src="img/white-bg1.png" alt="">
    </section>
    <section class="title clearfix">
           <h1>СЕДОНА — небольшой городок в АРИЗОНЕ, <br>
               зАСЛУЖИвающий большего!</h1>
           <p>Рассмотрим 5 причин, по которым Седона круче, чем гранд каньон!</p>
          </section>
    <section class="two-blocks clearfix">
            <div class="two-blocks-left">
                <h2 class="white-text">настоящий<br> городок</h2>
                <p class="white-text">№1</p>
                <p class="white-text">СЕДОНА — НЕ АТтРАКЦИОН ДЛЯ ТУРИСТОВ, <br>
                    ТАМ ТЕЧЕТ СВОЯ ЖИЗНЬ</p>
            </div>
            <div class="two-blocks-right"></div>
    </section>
    <section class="features clearfix">
        <div class="features-item ">
            <img src="img/icon-house.png" alt="">
            <h2>жилье</h2>
            <p>Рекомендуем пожить в настоящем <br> мотеле, все как в кино!</p>
        </div>
        <div class="features-item">
            <img src="img/icon-foot.png" alt="">
            <h2>еда</h2>
            <p>Всегда заказывайте ФИРМЕННЫЙ БУРГЕР,<br>
                Вы НЕ разочаруетесь!</p>
        </div>
        <div class="features-item">
            <img src="img/icon-gift.png" alt="">
            <h2>сувениры</h2>
            <p>Не только китайского, <br>
                но и местного производства!</p>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section class="two-blocks-2 clearfix">
        <div class="two-blocks-2-left"></div>
        <div class="two-blocks-2-right">
            <h2>там есть<br>мост дьявола</h2>
            <p>- №2 -</p>
            <p>Да, по нему можно пройти! 
                Если конечно вы осмелитесь</p>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section class="features-2 clearfix">
        <div class="features-item-2">
            <h2>небольшая площадь</h2>
            <p>- №3 -</p>
            <p>ВСЕ достопримечательности <br>
                находятся очень близко</p>
        </div>
        <div class="features-item-2">
            <h2>красивая дорога</h2>
            <p>- №4 -</p>
            <p>ЕХАТЬ В СЕДОНУ ИЗ ЛАС-ВЕГАСА совсем <br>
                НЕ СКУЧНО!</p>
        </div>
        <div class="features-item-2">
            <h2>мало туристов</h2>
            <p>- №5 -</p>
            <p>Большинство едет в гранд каньон и <br> толпится там</p>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section class="line ">
        <h3>заинтересовались?</h3>
        <p>Укажите предполагаемые даты поездки, <br>
            и мы покажем вам лучшие предложения гостиниц в седоне</p>
    </section>
    <section class="maps">
    </section>
    <footer class="clearfix">
        <div class="footer-div footer-div-1"><b>#visitsedona</b></div>
        <div class="footer-div footer-div-2">
            <div class="soc tw">
            <i class="fa fa-twitter fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </div>
        <div class="soc fb">
            <i class="fa fa-facebook fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="soc yt">
            <i class="fa fa-youtube-play fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </div>
    </div>
        <div class="footer-div footer-div-3">
        <p>website by</p> 
    <img src="img/htmlacademy.png" alt="">
    </div>
    
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Дайте код что бы могли разобраться, то что вы сказали в вопросе слишком мало что бы кто то мог помочь вам.

Comment: с таким формулировкой вопроса, вам прямиком на битву экстрасенсов...   они точно будут знать...  добавьте код, одни скришотом не понятно ничего...

Comment: Я подумал возможно, это ошибка часто встречаемая, и и так понятно :)

Comment: Кода немного, надеюсь кто-то поймет в чем трабл)

Comment: у вас .logo подвинуто на 168рх. дайте ему ширину так чтоб не выходило за пределы

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вашу проблему решит прописывание нужного width для класса .logo, например:

```
.logo {
    position: relative;
    left: 168px;
    z-index: 2;
    width: 100px
}
```

или overflow-x: hidden; для класса .container

```
.container {
    width: 1200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 15px 0px rgba(0, 1, 1, 0.2);
    background-color: #fff;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, теперь буду всегда ширину прописывать) П.С. А как вообще верстка для новичка?, полтора месяца опыта (3 макет), правда еще не закончен

Comment: Для 3-го макета ок. Я бы избегал использования относительного позиционирования для простых элементов типа лого или меню.